# sed: can't read /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Version (systeminfo)** 
Microsoft Windows Version 22H2 (compilation SO 19045.2673)

**WSL Version (wsl -l -v)**

| NAME | STATE | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * Ubuntu | Running | 2 |

**Ubuntu Version** 
Ubuntu-22.04

**Other Software** 
All normal windows software

**Repro Steps**  
sed: can't read /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: No such file or directory

**Expected Behavior** 
After opening the terminal or running it, it should be directed to the root directory.

**Actual Behavior**  
[image]

**Diagnostic Logs** 
I installed wsl Ubuntu distro using command wsl --install
It was workin fine during two days
today it is displaying message: **sed: can't read /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 1):

(cml) I fixed it by restarting WSL only:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` comes from the package `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`, which may be missing on your system, or removed for some reason.

To discover where packaged files come from, you may use `dpkg -S`, for example:

```
dpkg -S /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core: /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

To reinstate that file, simply run:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`

Comment: system does not allow me run command "dpkg -S /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades" the message is: -bash: dpkg: command not found. Remember that in my prompt I have: wslg [ ~ ]$, the same problem with sudo: -bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Ok, this is catastrophically broken. Do you have any data in this WSL machine you need? If so, I'd be inclined to copy it out, and destroy the machine and re-create it. While we could try to debug, chances are it's faster to just create a new machine.

Comment: inside my home user directory I have some folders, but if I run ls /home, there are only wslg folder but my user folder is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

On your windows system, right click on the Ubuntu terminal then select app settings.
Once you are there, click on repair. All should be fine now.

Comment: Some references to how and why this is a fix would be good.